# Problemas com a função merge

Tags: r, data.frame, merge

Estou tendo problemas com a função `merge` do nada ela parou de "merger" os data.frames.

Ao que parece ela ao invés de usar digamos o `cbind`, ela está usando `rbind` e o que é pior eco triplo (each=3). Pois dois data.frames de 40 linhas, estão resultado em um data.frame de 134 linhas.(sei que provavelmente não use essas funções mas apenas para elucidar o comportamento)

Já renomeei as colunas de ambos os data.frames deixando apenas a coluna que seria usada para "identificar" os dados. mas mesmo assim foi em vão.

Meu objetivo é agrupar dois desdobramentos de esquema fatorial para apresentar a interação significativa agrupando a resposta do teste de médias.

eu uso o código assim: `tab.final<-merge(tab1, tab2, by=c("means","means"))`

```
tab1<-structure(list(Talhão = c("Abacate", "Abacate", "Abacate", "Abacate", 
"Abacate", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana", "Banana", 
"Cacau", "Cacau", "Cacau", "Cacau", "Cacau", "Gliricidia", "Gliricidia", 
"Gliricidia", "Gliricidia", "Gliricidia", "Inga", "Inga", "Inga", 
"Inga", "Inga", "Manga", "Manga", "Manga", "Manga", "Manga", 
"Pupunha", "Pupunha", "Pupunha", "Pupunha", "Pupunha", "Seringueira", 
"Seringueira", "Seringueira", "Seringueira", "Seringueira"), 
    means = c(3.375, 2.875, 3.875, 3.125, 2.875, 3.125, 3.25, 
    2.875, 3.75, 3.625, 3.375, 4, 4, 2.125, 2.125, 3.625, 3.625, 
    3.625, 3.375, 2.125, 3.125, 2, 2, 2.125, 2, 3.875, 3.25, 
    2.875, 2.5, 2, 3.375, 3.375, 2.25, 2.375, 2.625, 2.125, 3.5, 
    3, 4, 3.75), let1 = c("A", "B", "A", "BC", "BC", "A", "AB", 
    "BC", "AB", "AB", "A", "A", "A", "D", "CD", "A", "AB", "AB", 
    "AB", "CD", "A", "C", "D", "D", "D", "A", "AB", "BC", "CD", 
    "D", "A", "AB", "CD", "CD", "CD", "B", "AB", "BC", "A", "A"
    ), Doses = c("0.001", "0.25", "0.5", "0.75", "1", "0.001", 
    "0.25", "0.5", "0.75", "1", "0.001", "0.25", "0.5", "0.75", 
    "1", "0.001", "0.25", "0.5", "0.75", "1", "0.001", "0.25", 
    "0.5", "0.75", "1", "0.001", "0.25", "0.5", "0.75", "1", 
    "0.001", "0.25", "0.5", "0.75", "1", "0.001", "0.25", "0.5", 
    "0.75", "1")), .Names = c("Talhão", "means", "let1", "Doses"
), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = "data.frame")



 tab2<-structure(list(Doses = c("0.001", "0.001", "0.001", "0.001", 
"0.001", "0.001", "0.001", "0.001", "0.25", "0.25", "0.25", "0.25", 
"0.25", "0.25", "0.25", "0.25", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", 
"0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.75", "0.75", "0.75", "0.75", "0.75", 
"0.75", "0.75", "0.75", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"
), means = c(3.375, 3.125, 3.375, 3.625, 3.125, 3.875, 3.375, 
2.125, 2.875, 3.25, 4, 3.625, 2, 3.25, 3.375, 3.5, 3.875, 2.875, 
4, 3.625, 2, 2.875, 2.25, 3, 3.125, 3.75, 2.125, 3.375, 2.125, 
2.5, 2.375, 4, 2.875, 3.625, 2.125, 2.125, 2, 2, 2.625, 3.75), 
    let2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("a", "ab", "b", "bc", "c"), class = "factor"), 
    Talhão = c("Abacate", "Banana", "Cacau", "Gliricidia", "Inga", 
    "Manga", "Pupunha", "Seringueira", "Abacate", "Banana", "Cacau", 
    "Gliricidia", "Inga", "Manga", "Pupunha", "Seringueira", 
    "Abacate", "Banana", "Cacau", "Gliricidia", "Inga", "Manga", 
    "Pupunha", "Seringueira", "Abacate", "Banana", "Cacau", "Gliricidia", 
    "Inga", "Manga", "Pupunha", "Seringueira", "Abacate", "Banana", 
    "Cacau", "Gliricidia", "Inga", "Manga", "Pupunha", "Seringueira"
    )), .Names = c("Doses", "means", "let2", "Talhão"), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: O problema é que sua coluna de mesclagem não possui valores únicos, então no merge acontece uma combinação de diversos elementos.

Comment: percebi isso agora kkk, mas sabe de alguma opção que combinação múltipla neste caso?

Comment: Comigo funcionou à primeira: `tab.final <- merge(tab1, tab2, by = "means"); tab.final <- tab.final[!duplicated(tab.final), ]`. Mas é evidente que vai ter muitas combinações de linhas, veja só, por exemplo, o caso `means = 2.00`. Depois de remover as linhas duplicadas fica com 102 linhas.

Comment: Rui entendi, porém deveria ter apenas 40 linhas, o que está ocorrendo é que como estou usando a coluna means para merger, nela contem dados, que não são duplicados, pois apresentam doses, e ou talhão diferente, embora as médias seja iguais como é o caso de médias 2.00... outra coisa que percebi porém não informei é que na coluna Doses, eu não sei porque cargas d'água, quando uso a função `HSD.test` do pacote `agricolae`, ele plota na coluna **trt**, alguns espaços.. o que acredito eu que seja esse outro impasse para eu não estar conseguindo rodar.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver usando as funções `rbind` e `cbind` combinadas com as funções `eval(parse(text=paste`:

```
eval(parse(text=paste(c('tabela<-rbind(',rep("",(nv1*nv2)-1)),'cbind(tab1[tab1$Talhão=="',rep(lf1,each=nv2),'" & tab1$Doses=="',lf2,'",],tab2[tab2$Doses=="',lf2,'" & tab2$Talhão=="',rep(lf1,each=nv2),'",])',c(rep(",",(nv2*nv1)-1),")"),sep="")))
```

em que: 
`lf1<-levels(tab1$Talhão)`;`nv1<-length(summary(tab1$Talhão))`
`lf2<-levels(tab2$Doses)`;`nv2<-length(summary(tab2$Doses))`

Mas gostaria de um comando mais simples ao estilo `merge(tab1, tab2, by=c("means","means"))`

Comment: Com os dados da pergunta, deu `<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`.

Comment: corrigi os data.frames copie tab1 e tab2 de novo caso queira! desculpe o transtorno, é que tive de substituir o código para colar aqui e não me dei conta que faltava colunas nos dois data.frames.

Answer (score 0):

Se você usasse o `bind_rows` do `dplyr` não chegaria no que você quer?

`tab.final <- bind_rows(tab1, tab2)`

Nesse caso você teria um `data.frame` de 80 linhas.

Se não, você poderia elucidar melhor onde exatamente você quer chegar?